# Apply hover effect after infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I have a hover image function which for some reason does not apply on new content loaded with infinite scroll.

This is the hover function:

```
function hover_overlay_article() {

     jQuery('a.thumblink, a.rating').each(function() {

     jQuery(this).hover( function() {
        $selector =  jQuery(this).parent().children('a.thumblink').children('img');
        $selector.stop().animate({opacity : .1}, 250, 'easeOutCubic');
    }, function() {
        $selector.stop().animate({opacity : 1}, 250, 'easeOutCubic');
    });

  });
}

hover_overlay_article();
```

And this is my infinite scroll:

```
<script>
  var infinite_scroll = {
  loading: {
img:"/_assets/images/ajax-loader.gif",
msgText: "",
finishedMsg: ""
},
   "nextSelector":"a.next.page-numbers",
   "navSelector":"div.pagination",
   "itemSelector":"div.fullarticle",
   "contentSelector":".articlecontainer"
};

 jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
</script>
```

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `hover_overlay_article()` in your `callback()` function. Try something like that:

```
<script>
    var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            img:"/_assets/images/ajax-loader.gif",
            msgText: "",
            finishedMsg: ""
        },
        "nextSelector":"a.next.page-numbers",
        "navSelector":"div.pagination",
        "itemSelector":"div.fullarticle",
        "contentSelector":".articlecontainer"
        }, function(arrayOfNewElems) {
            hover_overlay_article();
        });

    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
</script>
```

If it works then you can try changing your code to only run your function on the newest elements. The way it is now the first elements are going to be affected again by your jQuery method. Here's an example of what you could do:

```
function(arrayOfNewElems) {
    for(var i=0;i<arrayOfNewElems.length;i++)
    hover_overlay_article(arrayOfNewElems[i]);
}
```

Comment: I've copied the first code but i'm not sure where or how to use the following:

function(arrayOfNewElems) {
                for(var i=0;i<arrayOfNewElems.length;i++)
                    hover_overlay_article(arrayOfNewElems[i]);
            }

Comment: This would be an updated, more optimized version. It would require you to rewrite your `hover_overlay_article()` function so that it accepts a parameter. Your jQuery could therefore be applied only to the newest elements loaded by Infinite Scroll and not to all the page like it is the case now.

Comment: i've tried the first bit of code (the <script>var infinite_scroll.... </script>) but i'm receiving an error saying: "SyntaxError: missing : after property id function(arrayOfNewElems) {"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i'm still receiving the same error. You can see the error here: http://www.vantagemag.com/cat/news/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27734/discussion-between-mm2703-and-user2093301)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
      var infinite_scroll = {
      loading: {
    img:"/_assets/images/ajax-loader.gif",
    msgText: "",
    finishedMsg: ""
    },
       "nextSelector":"a.next.page-numbers",
       "navSelector":"div.pagination",
       "itemSelector":"div.fullarticle",
       "contentSelector":".articlecontainer"
    }, function(arrayOfNewElems){

        hover_overlay_article();
    });

     jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
    </script>
```

Note that this registres duplicate events for hover on existing elements. You should remove those first, or do something with the 'arrayOfNewElements'.